# how to send fax in iphone

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode

Is there anyone that have done this sort of thing?

I have created a UITable compose of contact informations which are phone numbers, email add, and a website.

Sending email, calling a number and visiting the site when tapping the cells in the table are easily done, the only thing left to do is sending a fax.

I've search for answers yet nothing really gives me what I need.
There are suggestions of coordinating with internet/web fax provider but most of them aren't free.

Can anyone please give any more idea on how to do this? OR point me to the nearest thing to accomplish this.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sending a fax isn't free so fax provider aren't free.
If you want to provide fax feature to your user you have to pay.

The only solution i see is to send email instead of fax.